# Need advice on creating a new ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax

I am creating a new ASP.NET application that is heavy on UI. I am leaning towards the Web form model over MVC as I am very familar with it.

I have a few questions

1. The UI lets users do tasks such as reorder table rows, do drag and drop, interact with images etc and the changes are saved to the database without clicking on the "Save" button. I understand this can be done using AJAX. What architecture needs to be used (JQuery with a WS call? ASP.NET AJAX?). Is implementing this kind of functionality complex and time consuming?
2. Is there any value in using a 3rd party toolkit such as Telerik or go with the native ASP.NET Ajax control toolkit?
3. I want to have the same look and feel as other Web 2.0 applications out there. Are there any design templates that could give me a headstart?

Any help is really appreciated.

**EDIT
Can you also throw some light on the architecture of a AJAX ASP.NET application?**

1. I have always worked with apps where the business logic and the data layer were separate projects. It appears that a AJAX app tends to use a web service. Does this mean that BL and the DAL are now webservices?
2. Can I use static page methods if i want to avoid a web service?**

Answer (score 4):

The control market around web forms is quite a bit more mature than MVC so tools from companies like Telerik, Devexpress, Infragistics will have a more mature implementation and broader base of support. Most all of those will do the things you mentioned across major browsers.

THAT SAID...

Consider MVC, when you put an application into the field it will probably be there for many many years, regardless of what you may think; now there is a good chance it might still be used in 10 years so make a decision like this with an eye to the future. MVC and jQuery make a powerful combo that can afford you rich functionality often commensurate with what the third party control vendors put out.

As far as design template, there are several sites like TemplateMonster which can give you a jump start.

Comment: I would agree that selecting MVC is a future-looking decision, but on that same note Webforms isn't going anywhere for a while, and if a developer doesn't have the client-side know-how that MVC would require of them, it is probably more sensible to go with something already tried, tested, and implemented.

Comment: Agreed. Just thought I would throw out both points to consider.

Answer (score 1):

The decision towards web forms or MVC is one that should place heavy focus on whether or not you have the necessary experience and comfort with working with all the client-side code that MVC requires you to implement yourself. By choosing MVC you will have to sacrifice the convenience of the countless pre-made ASP.NET controls already out there and instead build your own controls or implement alternatives from libraries like jQuery. From what you're describing, it sounds like web forms may be a better way to go for you.

1) This can be done as you say with jQuery and a WS call, and, from the sounds of it would be no small task to implement. Complex and time consuming? Yes.

2) There is definitely value in going with a control toolkit like Telerik (or [AJAX Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajax/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/)), just make sure they already do something similar to what you're trying to create or you're just wasting your time.

3) Can't help you with this one, personally.

Answer (score 1):

This is all asp.net 3.5 http://dropthings.omaralzabir.com/

The book you need is called:
Building a web 2.0 portal using asp.net

It includes drag and drops...etc etc

[http://www.amazon.com/Building-Web-2-0-Portal-ASP-NET/dp/B0026OR2SQ/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1256568264&sr=8-2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0026OR2SQ)

[Edit adding to your comments]
1) No DL and BL can still be compiled assemblies / dlls in other projects.  It doesn't change whether they are web service or not.  You may want to pick up a book and understand what AJAX is.  I assumed you knew it..visit the asp.net / ajax.net website and get up to speed on it.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you read this blog post from Rob Conery:
http://blog.wekeroad.com/blog/i-spose-ill-just-say-it-you-should-learn-mvc/

I was tempted to build an application using web forms because that's what I was familiar with and learning a new framework was a bit daunting.  Going with MVC was definitely more difficult, but I'm now so glad I did.  MVC offers great separation of concern, great control over the markup, works well with jQuery, and is suitable for TDD.  Knowing what I know now, I will never willingly build an application using web forms again.

Which ever way you go, good luck.